# plugin not hooking to my custom hook

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, hooks

I am trying to hook my plugin to my custom hook in my header.php but it doesn't seem to work but if i hook to my header through the function.php everything works perfectly. Does anyone have any idea how I can get it to work.

header.php

```
<?php logo_hook(); ?>
```

function.php

```
function logo_hook(){
do_action('logo_hook' );
echo 'function is working';
}
```

logo.php //this is my plugin

```
add_action( 'logo_hook', 'displayLogo');
function displayLogo( $text ) {
        $logo .= 'Plugin text...';
        return $text ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should using `do_action` in your header.php

```
do_action( 'logo_hook' );
```

And adding a value on this section with below function:

```
function add_text() {
    echo 'Hello world!';
}
add_action( 'logo_hook', 'add_text' );
```